# Where to swap image if broken

Tags: javascript, jquery, onerror

I use lots of images on a page which are loaded into DOM eg

```
html += '<img src="'+image.preview+'" title="View larger image" alt="'+image.item_title+'" height="'+image.display_height+'" width="'+image.display_width+'">';
```

The data comes from an ajax call and is in a FOR loop, one for each image. I have two images refs in case one is broken `image.preview` and `image.preview2` (I use two as image.preview is local but in case of error then image.preview2 is original image)

If `image.preview` is broken I want to switch to `image.preview2`

I'm trying the following but not sure where to place it?

```
$('img').on('error', function() { this.src = image.preview2; });
```

I've tried before the `html +=`, after, in the middle of but nothing seems to work - any ideas?

Comment: Read the comment directly above you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Figured out the easiest wasy to do it is inline:

```
html += '<img src....onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src=\''+image.preview2+'\';">';
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `preview2` image source is for every image different, then I suggest doing it within the `for` loop like this:

```
for(n in images) {
    var image = images[n];

    // create jQuery object (is not in the DOM jet)
    $img = $('<img title="View larger image" alt="' + image.item_title + '" height="' + image.display_height + '" width="' + image.display_width + '">');

    // is there an preview src?
    if(typeof image.preview == 'Undefined' || image.preview == '') { //nopes
        $img.attr('src', image.preview2);
    } else { //yes
        $img.attr('src', image.preview);
    }

    // add the image to the DOM
    $('#id_of_element').append($img);
}
```

Comment: Much better solution, I endorse this :)

Comment: This is checking if the url reference exists to the image as opposed to if the image is actually there though, correct? Or am I reading it wrongly?

Comment: It checks if the `preview` property of the image is set. So it will not check if the image exists.

Answer (score 0):

you can do:

```
var newImg = $('<img src="'+image.preview+'" title="View larger image" alt="'+image.item_title+'" height="'+image.display_height+'" width="'+image.display_width+'">');
newImg.on('error', function() { this.src = image.preview2; }); 

and then

<the html container>.append(newImg);
```

this will make sure your image has all settings before it is added to the dom and fetched.

Answer (score 0):

> example:

```
function setDefaultImage(img)
{
  img.src = "images/candidates/human.jpg";
}
```

hope this will help you..

> in your scenario..

```
html += '<img src="'+image.preview+'" title="View larger image" alt="'+image.item_title+'" height="'+image.display_height+'" width="'+image.display_width+'" onerror="'setDefaultImage(this)'">';

 function setDefaultImage(img)
    {
      img.src = "image.preview2";
    }
```

Comment: This is close but I get the error NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://myurl.com/pages/image.preview2 - its not bringing in the reference properly

Comment: may be went wrong with the path..